# How do I play an audio file when using Fulfillment with Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm making a Google Assistant action, similar to what Google does when you say "Play an E note".

I've managed to get my nodejs app to reply back the parameter, but now I need to pass an audio file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to place the audio file on a hosting service somewhere (Firebase Hosting is a good choice, particularly if you're also using Firebase Cloud Functions for your Action, but any place that can serve a file via HTTPS works) and then send back [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) as your response that includes the audio.

This might look something like this:

```
var audioUrl = 'https://example.com/audiofile.mp3';
var msg = `<speak><audio src="${audioUrl}"></audio></speak>`
app.tell( msg );
```

Adjust this for your own audio file, and you might want to use `app.ask()` instead of tell if you are prompting the user to reply to your audio.

Comment: Thank you, no, I'm not prompting for an answer. The audio file is the answer :)